# Нужно пропарсить файл.log

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, логирование

Уважаемые, нужна помощь. Есть файл с логами.
Нужно узнать:

1. Максимальное количество запросов от одного клиента?
2. С какого IP адреса было сделано больше всего запросов?
3. Минимальное количество запросов?
4. Среднее количество запросов от одного клиента?

```
import collections
user = 'users.log'
​fp = open(user)
file_lines = fp.readlines()
fp.close()
​counter = collections.Counter()
lenCounter = len(counter)
    ​
for line in file_lines:
    words = line.split()
    words_first = words[0]
    counter[words_first] += 1
```

.log файл - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZFcBSSbCqlnidqtz6EJJlm1VRzigM69C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ну и вопрос, собственно, в чем? Что конкретно не получается? как выглядит log-файл?

Comment: Можешь добавить пример `.log` файла?

Comment: @Javascript Dev https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZFcBSSbCqlnidqtz6EJJlm1VRzigM69C/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

with open("users.log") as infile:
    cntr = Counter(map(lambda line: line.split()[0], infile))
    max_cnt, *_, min_cnt = cntr.most_common()
    avg = sum(cntr.values()) / len(cntr)
    print(
        f"{max_cnt[1]:<20}Максимальное количество запросов от одного клиента.",
        f"{max_cnt[0]:<20}С какого IP адреса было сделано больше всего запросов.",
        f"{min_cnt[1]:<20}Минимальное количество запросов.",
        f"{avg:<20.2f}Среднее количество запросов от одного клиента.",
        sep='\n'
    )
```

**Output**

```
1733                Максимальное количество запросов от одного клиента.
23.101.169.3        С какого IP адреса было сделано больше всего запросов.
1                   Минимальное количество запросов.
14.14               Среднее количество запросов от одного клиента.
```